# unable to fetch a page and get Response code 403 (Forbidden) error

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, node.js-got

Using `got` I want to get the web page like this:

```
const { data } = await got.get(`https://www.powerthesaurus.org/trust/synonyms`);
console.log(data)
```

But this gives me this error:

> HTTPError: Response code 403 (Forbidden)

**Using axios I get the same error 403.**

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you checked the [closed issues](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/issues?q=is%3Aissue+403+is%3Aclosed) to see if any solution pops up. Note I tried this with node's native `fetch` and it worked fine.

Comment: How did you use fetch I get 403 even using fetch, Note: I'm testing in localHost

Comment: Even in server side  get 403

Comment: @Andy please tell me how you did it with fetch ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7AKUgdn7.